# Web app similar to Google Hangouts with remote desktop control and no installation required

Tags: web-apps

I'm teaching people IT related subjects remotely and want to ensure them a seamless experience. I'm looking for a web app that:

- would allow me to run meetings through a web browser,
- with the possibility of a remote desktop control (both mouse and keyboard),
- without the need to download & install any additional software,
- without the need for an invited person to register on any website (people can just join via links),
- I'm happy to pay for it if it exists :)

Back in the days google hangouts had a plugin that allowed remote desktop control. This along with the paid, commercial google account allowing to invite non-google members to join hangouts was a perfect solution. However, this stack is not available anymore. Now, I need to separately install "chrome remote desktop" plugin what requires not only to use that specific browser but also going through a plugin installation process. Any ideas on other apps/tricks that could help me to achieve that?